# Delete a row in parse using c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, parse-platform

I am trying to delete a row in ListView but I keep getting the error "Parse.ParseException: Object not found".

```
private async void ApproveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int pos = (int)(((ImageButton)sender).GetTag(Resource.Id.imageBtnApprove));
    leaves.RemoveAt(pos);
    activity.RunOnUiThread(() => this.NotifyDataSetChanged());

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("LeaveInfo");
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> applyeave = await query.FindAsync();
    foreach (var record in applyeave)
    {
        await record.DeleteAsync();
        await record.SaveAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is value of variable 'pos' ?  You are calling a method GetTag() and then trying to cast the value to an integer which willnot work.  You have to get the ListView object then delete the row from the ListView. GetTag is a method that is used on a html object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the item from the `listview`, First of all, Open your `adapter` of `listview`, add a method. `data`is container of data in my demo, data is a type of `list`.

```
 public void RemoveItemAt(int position)
 {
        data.RemoveAt(position);
 }
```

Then, you could add a event listener to `listview` or other view, I add the click listener in listview here.

```
        lv_test = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lv_test);

        lv_test.Adapter = adapter;

        lv_test.ItemClick += (s, e) =>
        {
            OnClick(e.Position);
        };
    public void OnClick(int position)
    {
      //call RemoveItemAt method in adapter
        adapter.RemoveItemAt(position);
      //notify the data changed
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I am not familiar with `parse-server`. There is simple demo about removing data from  listview.
https://github.com/851265601/DeleteItemListviewDemo

Answer (score 0):

You can delete an object with the code below:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("WeChatUser");
ParseObject myObject = await query.GetAsync("<PARSE_OBJECT_ID>");
await myObject.DeleteAsync();
```

I got the code above from API Reference, which you can have access to a platform that automatically generates docs for any objects saved in your database:

https://blog.back4app.com/2018/12/14/the-api-reference-tool/